# Properly setting up indices for sectionIndexTitlesForTableView

Tags: uitableview, ios5, indexing

All,

I added a section index (indices) to my tableview and it works fine. Tap on "K" and you go to section "K". I am now trying to add the magnifying glass to the section index by prepending it to my indices array and of course, the section index does not map cleanly to the sections because the index is now off by one. "A" used to be at index 0, now the magnifying glass is at index 0 so it's all off now by one index. You tap on "J" and get "K", etc. Can someone explain to me the best way to add the magnifying glass? Thanks

```
-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

NSMutableArray *indices = [NSMutableArray array];

//Add the magnifying glass as the first element in the indices array
[indices addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];

for(int i = 0; i<sorted.count; i++){

   [indices addObject:[sorted objectAtIndex:i]];



}   
return indices;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by using fast enumeration to populate the index by first adding the magnifying glass and then adding all of the keys: A,B,C...X,Y,Z...1,2,...8,9

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
  NSMutableArray *indices =
    [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sorted count]+1];

   [indices addObject:UITableViewIndexSearch];

    for (NSString *item in sorted)
      [indices addObject:[item substringToIndex:1]];


    return indices;
 }
```